# Asp.net ajax+ Jquery: EndRequestHandler(sender, args)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am working on asp.net, addon with JQuery.

After registering endRequest inside ready() function of Jquery.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

For the function:

> function EndRequestHandler(sender,
>   args) {}

How could I retrieve the ID of the button where I click based on 'sender' and 'args'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ID of *which* button? IIRC the ID of the control that caused the postback isn't available here, only when sending the request.

Comment: Hi,

I meant the control (the button) that I clicked to raise the postback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
        alert(sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id);            
    }
}
```